# How to properly download and update ListView progressively?

Tags: android, adapter, android-listview

Currently I have a service that downloads about 500 records of somewhat complex data, when the user request a refresh or the cached data expires, the service downloads the data and caches it into a database.  In the activity where the list is shown I'm listening for broadcasts from the service about the download progress.  Every time I get a progress status I run:

```
mAdapter.getCursor().requery();
```

I see my data progressively filling the ListView as its downloading which is nice... But I have two big concerns.

1. My solution seems very complex and dirty.
2. This solution won't work on Android 3.0 and later.

I'm looking for feedback on how to better approach this.  There has to be a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're concerned about the use of `requery()` and an alternative for Android 3.0, see the [deprecation note](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html#FLAG_AUTO_REQUERY) in the `CursorAdaptor` documentation, which explains using `LoaderManager` and `CursorLoader` as an alternative.

Based on your explanation of the requirements of your app, the way you're doing it is probably the most idiomatic approach, and I wouldn't really call it "dirty".  Seems straight forward to me.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I looked at the deprecation note and what sucks is that it's only available on API level 11.  I guess I might have to create a compatible reflection class for both methods... :(

Comment: Well, it's only deprecated, so since the support is still there, it's not vital that you move to the newer API yet.  You would only need a compatibility wrapper if you intend to support later SDK levels, and `requery()` is removed in one of the SDK levels you want to support -- in other words: only if you intend to support both the `requery()` method, and the newer `CursorLoader` method.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest providing a loading screen when the user refreshed, instead of progressively populating your list. This seems cleaner to me. At any rate you will have to requery the cursor whether it be progressively or at the end, so not sure which part you think could use improvement.

Comment: My requirement for this list is to avoid placing a loading screen since its a lot of records and on slow connections this makes the app feel slow.  The idea is to give the user the chance to surf the list as it's being populated.